OpenSSL BIO_do_handshake does not put any errors on the stack
I'm trying to debug a TLS handshake problem from the server side.  The client sends something the server doesn't like in the Client Hello packet, and I'm trying to figure out what it is.
After setting up a context, setting options, loading the server certificate, etc., the code creates a BIO object from the context.  After that, it calls BIO_do_handshake to perform the handshake.  BIO_do_handshake returns -1, indicating an error.  But when I call ERR_get_error immediately after that, it returns 0, meaning that there are no error codes on the stack.
Here's the code.  (It currently uses the OpenSSL 1.0.2 API.)
long
perform_handshake(BIO *bio)
{
    long rc;

    do {
        rc = BIO_do_handshake(bio);
        if (rc <= 0) {
            unsigned long errcode;
            char *errstr;

            syslog(LOG_ERR, "BIO_do_handshake returned %d\n", rc);

            while (errcode = ERR_get_error()) {
                errstr = ERR_error_string(errcode, NULL);
                syslog(LOG_ERR, "%s\n", errstr);
            }
        }
    } while (rc <= 0 && BIO_should_retry(bio));

    return rc;
}

I get the message "BIO_do_handshake returned -1" in my syslog output, but no error strings.
Are my expectations about BIO_do_handshake wrong?  Does it not put errors on the stack?  If not, how am I supposed to get detailed information about the handshake problem?
(Note: all of the code works fine if the handshake doesn't fail.)

Can you try with a later version of OpenSSL?  The OpenSSL 1.0.2 documentation for BIO_do_handshake() literally has this for return values: "RETURN VALUES¶
TBA".  That leads me to suspect the error handling might also be incomplete.  Depending on how you're setting up your SSL connection, you might also want to try the command-line utility with openssl s_client -connect ... and see what happens.  Also, OpenSSL 1.0.2 is rather outdated, and if the server only supports new cipher suites there may be no common cipher suites with 1.0.2.

The problem with using s_client is that it's the server that's rejecting the Client Hello packet, and the client receives no information from the server other than the handshake failed.  (I can see this in a network trace.)  As for using a newer version of OpenSSL, it would take a lot of work, and all I'm trying to do is create a one-off debug version of the server to give to a customer to gather the information I need.  Ugh.  Maybe I'll dig into the OpenSSL source code to see if there's something I can do there.

If the client hello is summarily rejected like that, given that it contains the TLS version(s) and cipher suites the client supports - and not much else - that would seem to indicate the client and the server have no common TLS versions and/or cipher suites.  There aren't many other reasons to reject a client hello.

It can be because one or more of the client's proposals have no matches on the server, not just the TLS version.  That's why I want to create a debug version--the TLS versions do match up (both sides support TLS 1.2).  Worse, when I compare the various algorithms proposed by the client to those in the server configuration, there's at least one overlap for each one.  This is why I'm stumped.

both sides support TLS 1.2 What method(s) have you used to determine that the server supports TLS v1.2 and is not restricted to TLS v1.3?  See https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/55752/why-does-wireshark-show-version-tls-1-2-here-instead-of-tls-1-3 (and a lot of others...)

That's why I want to create a debug version Just get something that supports TLS 1.3 and see if that works instead of trying to dig down into the depths of something that stopped being supported five years ago.

I wrote some rudimentary code to just handle the initial handshake but with OpenSSL 1.1.1.  My code above now properly logs error detail.  So this does appear to be a problem with 1.0.2.  I'm going to use my mini daemon with the customer to figure out the root cause of their problem.

The problem is that OpenSSL 1.0.2 doesn't appear to properly put error events on the stack during BIO_do_handshake.  The same code with OpenSSL 1.1.1 gets a non-zero error stack and correctly logs the errors.
